# Update Custom field with Expression in Jira Cloud

Tags: jira

I'm using Jira cloud. i have a custom field called vendor case no, and I'd like a second field called vendor case link to be populated when an uissue is create. For example, if a user creates and issue with vendor case no 123456, I want vendor case link to be https://domain.com/support/apex/myportalHome#case/detail/123456

Unfortunately, I can't seem to use groovy script or expressions (AFAIK) in Jira cloud

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still script a solution, but it'll take a bit more work compared to using a standalone JIRA server with the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview).

JIRA Cloud supports [Webhooks](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks). That means you can provide your own REST resource which will be called on the issue events that you configure it for.

You'll have to implement your own REST resource to use as webhook and run a webserver (Tomcat, Jetty, Netty, ...) but that way you can still implement any behaviour you desire. Ie. your REST resource can use the JIRA REST api to update the just created issue with a correct value for the "vendor case link" custom field.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried that that might be the case